# Can i run 200 schedule with in 1 hour range with different name?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

Based on the below link, I am aware that we can schedule the job upto 100 per hour. Can i schedule more than 100 job with different name.

JobName1 - 20
JObName2 - 80 
JobName3 - 80  - what happens here ?

Is that one transaction or it can allow us to schedule more than 100 for different transaction.

[Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159454/governor-limits-in-scheduling-scheduledapex-jobs-how-much-and-where-to-find-th)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can never have more than 100 scheduled jobs active in an org. There's a hard limit of 100 pending scheduled jobs **total**. You have to abort/delete those jobs before you can create more. This also implies a limit of 100 scheduled jobs per transaction, since there can never be more than 100 total scheduled jobs.

Comment: We want to re-try REST call only once after 15 minutes if the call is failed when we save the case record.  Any thought on that.

Comment: @bharath How I handled this previously is to have a custom object that stores failed requests and then have a single scheduled class that's called to retry the failed requests.